# Why "Export to New Stream Analytics Project" is disable

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I would like to use Visual Studio to debug the query of Azure Stream Analytics. I use the Server Explorer to open my Stream Analytics project but why the option "Export to New Stream Analytics Project" is disabled?

[image: "Export to New Stream Analytics Project" is disabled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, if your job contains ADLS or powerBI output, we will disable this function as we do not support them. We will support it in next release, thanks for your feedback

Comment: Does that mean that there is currently no way to integrate a Stream Analytics job which uses ADLS or PowerBI into a source controlled environment?

Comment: there is no way to integrate it now, we will release this feature very soon